# (Int) -> $T4 is not identical to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift

My problem had asked as the Title. Let me describe it.

1. I declared an instance of NSMutableArray which called `items` and assign `20` to it's `capacity`.

   `var items =  NSMutableArray()
   items = NSMutableArray(capacity: 20)`
2. I used UICollectionView in my App, and a delegate method of UICollectionView had an error.

   `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, moveItemAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
       var thing: NSString = items(fromIndexPath.item)
       self.items.removeObjectAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
       self.items.insertObject(thing, atIndex: toIndexPath.item)
   }`

   The third line of method, `var thing: NSString = items(fromIndexPath.item)` ,returns an error --- `(Int) -> $T4 is not identical to NSMutableArray`

   Please tell me how solve it.

   A great appreciation for your time and guide.

   Ethan Joe

Comment: typo, use square brackets to retrieve from an array: `var thing: NSString = items[fromIndexPath.item]`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Your answer solved my problem. And it still needs to add 'as NSString' at the end of code.

Comment: voted to close for this typo

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new guy to Stack OverFlow. I don't know how to vote up the answer in the Comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using native Swift string arrays which are strongly typed:

```
var items:[String] = []
```

Also, you need to use square brackets when retrieving from the array:

```
let thing = items[fromIndexPath.item]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really want to vote up your answer. But I just have only 14 reputations.